# simulate two correlated ordinal variables in R

Tags: r, fixed, simulate, ordinal, correlated

I would like to simulate two correlated ordinal variables in R. Both variables consist of three different levels (1/1,1/0,0/0), which each are sampled from a fixed frequency of 1 and 0 (let’s say 1=.20;0=.80). The frequency of the three levels (1/1,1/0,0/0) for each variable is variable and depends on the correlation between Var1 and Var2.

```
n=1000

rho=.70

Var1=sample(c(1/1,1/0,0/0),n,replace=T,prob=c(a,b,c))

Var2=?

cor(Var1,Var2)=rho
```

How do I fix the pool of 1 and 0 from which the levels of each variable are sampled? 
How do I simulate the variables to be correlated at level rho? Something simple such as

```
rho*Var1+sqrt(1-rho^2)*Var2
```

doesn't work here.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: [This answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15040/59815) should get you close. *Ordinal variable* is SPSS terminology, which is IMHO is imprecise, in effect you will be interested in obtaining an ordered factor.

Comment: check [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SimCorMultRes/SimCorMultRes.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, @mtoto, I have tried SimCorMultRes, but still haven't figured out how to vary the frequency of the multinominal response levels according to rho,while fixing the frequency of elements (i.e. 1 and 0).

Answer (score 0):

Correlation does not make sense for these variables, as they are not ordered. Insted you can use 0,1,2 as the values.

In this cyse, this could help you:

```
n=1000

rho=.70

Var1=sample(c(0,1,2),n,replace=T,prob=c(1/3,1/3,1/3))

index=sample(c(0,1),n,replace=T,prob=c(1-rho,rho))
index<-index==1
Var2=sample(c(0,1,2),n,replace=T,prob=c(1/3,1/3,1/3))

Var2[index]<-Var1[index]

  cor(Var1,Var2)
```